# Modify the space between double vertical lines in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

Is there a way to change the space between double vertical lines `||` within a tabular environment?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l||l|}
    \hline
    cell 1 & cell2 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve: Are you looking to increase or to decrease the space between double vertical lines?

Comment: @Mico I would like to increase the space between these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\setlength\doublerulesep{4cm}
```

would make them further apart.

Comment: Interesting (?) little factoid: The default value of `\doublerulesep` is `2pt` in most (well-known) document classes.

Comment: @David Thanks that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mico so conservative, 4cm is more noticeable.